Exit node location conflict
Can somebody please explain to me why the behavior depicted in the image below occurs?  The Tor browser says that the exit node is in Sweden, but the website that is loaded in the browser claims that my IP address is in USA.  That's weird, right?  Or am I misunderstanding something?
Also why can't https://whatismyipaddress.com/ see the ipv4 address?  May that be related to its "incorrect" (I don't actually know who to believe as correct here) perception of the location of the exit node?


You have some multiple questions tightly packed up, so let me address them:

Whatismyip - so as many websites to "know your IP" stuff - are using deanonymizing scripts. And that affects not just a geo detection, but the detection possibility itself
Even the most expensive geo to ip databases are not accurate by 100%, so misdetects are happening even for a home addresses: for example one of the home ISP addresses was detected as from Amsterdam instead of Moscow without any VPN or other stuff, just by it's number
The tag "your location may be exposed" is related just to a scaring you tactics, so you'll turn off your Tor or VPN to avoid it. No website can "detect" that your location can be exposed due to the simple reason: it's not able to know who's routing your signal regardless of the pathway(plain/Tor/VPN)

Update: russian version by request with broader explaination
В вопросе на самом деле несколько очень близко связанных между собой вопросов, поэтому пройдёмся по ним по порядку:

Wahtismyip - как и многие другие сайты - использует не просто скрипты определения геолокации, а в принципе проводит детект всего, что можно, и, нередко, деанонимизацию - взять тот же Cloudflare. И такие скрипты дают интересные глюки
Даже самые дорогие и "полные"  базы данных геолокаций - вроде MaxMind GeoIP - не точны на 100%. У нас был случай: провайдер домашнего интернета в Москве выдал статичный адрес, который даже платный GeiIP определял как находившийся в Амстердаме. Просто по адресу - без какого-либо VPN. Он выдал его мне - так что я это всё сам проверил
Надписи "ваше местоположение возможно раскрыто" - это просто тактика запугивания. Ни один вэб-сайт не может при приёме запроса от клиента хоть каким-либо образом раскрыть его местоположение. Причина банальна: сайт не может знать фактический путь пакета с запросом к нему - как он шёл - напрямую, через VPN, Tor или ещё через что-либо. Он его просто принимает


Alexey, nothing about your answer makes sense probably because your English is not as strong and your TCP/IP.  Can you just answer in Russian?
